# Git still see my last user.name after changing

Tags: git

I have changed `user.name` and `email` to new account:

```
git config --global user.name "newusername"

git config --global user.mail "newmail@newmail.com"
```

then I pushed some staff to the new account on github of newusername user. Then I have logout and now want to push something to my old account. Again i type:

```
git config --global user.name "oldusername"

git config --global user.mail "oldmail@oldmail.com"
```

when I type:

```
git config --list
```

then I get:

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
user.email=oldmail@oldmail.com
user.name=oldusername
credential.helper=store
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/oldmail/oldproject.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

So i have cloned my project, made changes, commit and on `git push` I get:

```
remote: Permission to oldusername/oldproject.git denied to newusername.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/oldusername/oldproject.git/': The requested                                                                                                                                                                                                URL returned error: 403
 URL returned error: 403
```

HOW ???! Where is he seeing the newusername?!!!

Comment: `git push` doesn't care about your `user.name` or `user.mail`. It uses the credentials in your credential store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git credential-manager uninstall`

Answer (score 0):

To flesh out what @RaymondChen said, you're not necessarily pushing your own commits, you can easily be pushing a dozen or a hundred different people's commits if you're QA meister or some such lieutenant.  What matters first is your authorization to push to that repo at all, vetting the content itself is a separate task.

Comment: so how to delete that `newUser` and be as `oldUser` ?

Comment: shieeeet, finally only this helped: `git credential-manager uninstall`